# How to make DFT in matlab without FFT

Tags: fft, dft

Does anyone have a algorithm for DFT without FFT function in matlab?

and second question is how can I make zero padding in this algorithm?

Comment: Regarding the first question: have you tried `dftmtx()`?

Comment: how can I make dft to sine with this function?

Comment: You have to multiply your signal vector with the DFT matrix that is obtained with `dftmtx()` to obtain the DFT of your signal. The result is of course identical to the FFT. An example is shown [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dftmtx.html).

Comment: OK, I understood. I will try it. Thanks for the help. But is there somewhere the algorithm of the FFT function?

Comment: Well, the FFT algorithm is described in many books, the corresponding [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) or, of course, in the [famous paper by Cooley and Tukey](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1965-19-090/S0025-5718-1965-0178586-1/S0025-5718-1965-0178586-1.pdf).

Comment: And, regarding your second question: [Zero padding](http://www.bitweenie.com/listings/fft-zero-padding/) in this context is the process of appending zeros to your input signal, in doing so making the signal effectively longer and, hence, using a DFT of this (increased) length.

Comment: @applesoup I thought that zero padding makes it same length but increase resolution of the signal? in DFT

Comment: In the discrete domain, *resolution* and *length* are directly related: If you want a finer resolution, you will need more samples (in either the time or frequency domain). This is very obvious with digital images, for example: A larger number of pixels allows to resolve small details better. Regarding zero padding: By appending zeros to your original signal, you increase its length, but nothing more. The DFT of this zero padded signal, however, has a finer resolution by adding *interpolated values* between the original frequency bins.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the `applesoup`, you should try `dftmtx()`. However, if you want to write a code for generating the DFT matrix, here it is,

```
funtion dftmatrix = myDFTmtx(N)

    dftmatrix = [];
    for k = 0:N-1
        row = [];
        for n = 0:N-1
            row = [row exp(-j*2*pi*k*n/N)];
        end
        dftmatrix = [dftmatrix; row];
    end
end
```

The matrix returned by this function when multiplied with the time domain sequence or column vector, will return its DFT coefficients.

Comment: You can construct the DFT matrix with a single line in matlab, without any loop: take a look at [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/8829/4298).

Comment: @MattL. I don't think efficiency would be that much important for someone looking for DFT without FFT... ( I assume the statment "without any loop" implied inefficient)

Comment: @Fat32: efficiency, but also simplicity AND understanding of how matlab works (namely, with matrices). It's a different kind of thinking when programming, and I thought the author of the answer might be interested. Just additional info, nothing more than that ...

Comment: @MattL. yes I fully agree on the proper, efficient, or most importantly elegand use of Matlab language...

Comment: @MattL. Thanks for the additional info, It really helped me.